# Making an https.request with Node using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, promise

I have a script which requires me to use the node https module instead of something nicer. I am struggling to find documentation that explains how https.request really works.

I see plenty of examples but the way these functions are put together is rather cryptic to me.

I've put some comments in my code below to explain the areas that i do not understand.

My problem right now is my catch block isn't returning an error from the request. It gets to that condition but the e is empty. I am not sure how to properly handle errors here. I'm further confused by the need to 3 different conditions that result in reject of promise. How does this call to https have 3 ways to fail? Maybe my code is just wrong.

```
const https = require("https");

const payload = {
  username: "test",
  sendEmail: true,
};

callService(payload)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("This gives me nothing! does the reject not end up here? " + JSON.stringify(e));
  });

const callService = (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    const url = new URL(process.env.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
    const options = {
      host: url.host,
      port: 443,
      path: url.pathname,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": data.length,
      },
    };
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
        return reject(new Error("statusCode=" + res.statusCode)); 
        //so we did an Error class here but down below just reject(e), is that dumb?
      }

      //no idea wtf this is doing right here
      var body = [];
      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
      });

      //im turning the streamed data into a json object?
      res.on("end", function () {
        try {
          body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
        } catch (e) {
          //what would happen to trigger this error and where does it go?
          reject(e);
        }
        resolve(body); //yay?
      });
    });

    //wait we have to catch some other kind of error here? whats the difference between req and res?
    req.on("error", (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
  });
};
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Simply perform an https request? And why are u using promises afterall?

Comment: "*I am struggling to find documentation*" - you did read https://nodejs.org/api/https.html and https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest?

Comment: https.request uses callbacks (its 2nd argument) not Promises. If you would like to use promises, you can use the following module which ports the browser fetch to node : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: The reason for using promises was that there was some additional logic needed to process the request response and this provided a clean way to abstract the somewhat messy logic in the https.request function. I cannot use node-fetch due to limitations of the cloud solution where this function is living.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for that, i've since found that drilling into the doc for the http.ClientRequest class more helpful as it explains some of the details about how this request works. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Comment: `https.request()` is documented to "*return an instance of the http.ClientRequest class*", yes.

Comment: If anybody finding this in the future is running a very recent Node (~18 or later), you may have access to a built in global `fetch`.